# Trying to pass recent ID with scope_identity, and its error me : Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, scope-identity

Im trying to pass the recent ID that I just insert with Scope_Identity, 
and its giving me some weird stuff.
it says :

> : Specified cast is not valid

and refering to the line :

```
int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (Int32)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
```

this is the rest of the code :

```
string username = Session["Session"].ToString();

            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string knowWhichOne = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username='" + UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int userID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            knowWhichOne = "SELECT ClassID FROM Users WHERE Username='" + UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int classID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            knowWhichOne = "SELECT SchoolID FROM Users WHERE Username='"+UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int schoolID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            if (RadioWords.Checked == true)
            {
                 game = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                 game = 2;
            }
            string arr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr += ListBox.Items[i] +",";
            }

            string sqlqueryString = "INSERT INTO HistoryOfGames (GameID, UserID, LengthOfArray, NumberOfErrors, ClassID, SchoolID,Arrayarray) VALUES (@GameID, @UserID, @LengthOfArray, @NumberOfErrors, @ClassID, @SchoolID, @Arrayarray);" + "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

            SqlCommand commandquery = new SqlCommand(sqlqueryString, con);

            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("GameID", game);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("LengthOfArray", HowMany.Text);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("NumberOfErrors", 0);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("ClassID", classID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("SchoolID", schoolID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("Arrayarray", arr);

            commandquery.ExecuteNonQuery();





            int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (Int32)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            Response.Redirect("NowPlay.aspx?ID="+ IdOfRecentHistoryGame);
```

somebody has a clue ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your identity in the SQL table is an int?

Comment: The ID?
yeah.   positive 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `numeric(38,0)` since an `IDENTITY` can be defined on columns of types besides `int` (see [SQL Server - What are the data types supported in IDENTITY columns?](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2009/01/28/sql-server-what-are-the-data-types-supported-in-identity-columns.aspx)).

`ExecuteScalar` is returning a `decimal` as an `object`, which you cannot cast directly to `int`.  Instead, cast to `decimal` first, then to `int`:

```
int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (Int32)(Decimal)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() apparently doesn't actually return an Int in SQL server. I didn't know it couldn't be cast like you tried to, but apparently it can't.

The below link says that if the source column is an integer you shouldn't have to cast it at all, but this is worth a shot at any rate -

[How do I cast Scope_Identity() to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001854/how-do-i-cast-scope-identity-to-int) shows how to cast this within the SQL query in order to get an Integer out:

(Courtesy of Jose Basilio)

```
DECLARE @NewIdent Int
SET @NewIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Try assigning your variable to the output of that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
do you mean to place it in the query ?
if I do so, its giving me an error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Exactly, instead of "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", work the above declaration into the query and then select NewIdent instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Then, when you run: int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (Int32)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
commandquery.ExecuteScalar() should actually return an int.

Comment: weird.  its throwing me an error of : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Interesting...does it give any more information than that? I assume all you changed was the SQL query, right? None of the other code?
What SQL query are you using now?

Comment: It all worked out for me now.
the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY is actually correct. but I had to make (int)(decimal) to cast it. thanks again !